# FirstResponder missing redo:

Tags: objective-c, macos, undo, first-responder, redo

Why my FirstResponder in InterfaceBuilder's file is missing `redo:` connection (in `Received Actions` list)? `undo:` exists, but `redo:` doesn't. How could I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all, could you please elaborate?

Comment: In InterfaceBuilder's file (default name: MainMenu.xib) there always is object named `FirstResponder`. It always has some default connections. And if you want to implement `NSUndoManager` you need to use FirstResponder's connections `undo:/redo:`. And I have implemented `NSUndoManager`. Added `FirstResponder`'s `undo:` connection to button witch should do undo function. It works. Now I need `redo:` connection from `FirstResponder` to add redo function. And it always could be found in `FirstResponder`, but now there is no `redo:` connection in my `FirstResponder`. Why could it be so?

Comment: He means that when he has the `First Responder` placeholder item selected in a nib file, and has the connections inspector open, `undo:` is not among one of the listed `Received Actions`...

Comment: 4.5.2. I created new project and there exists both connections in first responder, but in my current project `redo:` doesn't exists

Answer (score 17):

This is a bug. The workaround is to throw this in a file somewhere:

```
@interface NSResponder (Redo)
- (IBAction)redo:(id)sender;
@end
```

Then make your connection in Interface Builder. Once that is done you can delete this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Xcode, it doesn't see the redo: action even though it is there. As a workaround you can create a custom action redo: for making the connection.

See my Radar here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/01/radar-interface-builders-first-responder-is-missing-some-editing-actions/