# How to associate a toolbar item button to Redo in a macOS app?

Tags: macos, toolbar

I have a macOS app with Toolbar where I would like to connect two buttons to Undo and Redo.

I connected the first in Storyboard with no problem by control-dragging the toolbar item to the First Responder icon in the window and choosing the -Undo action.

When trying to connect the second toolbar item, I noticed that the  Redo item is not present in the list.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirstResponder missing redo:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361298/firstresponder-missing-redo)

Comment: Thank you Ssswift

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the comment by Ssswift, I solved the problem by converting in Swift the Objective-C answer to the similar question: [FirstResponder missing redo:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361298/firstresponder-missing-redo)

I put this somewhere in the file (at file scope):

```
extension NSResponder {
    @IBAction func redo(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

Then the redo appeared in connection list and I got the possibility to connect the toolbar item to redo.

Finally I deleted the code as suggested in the answer and all worked fine.